# angular2 hide mdtooltip after clicking

Tags: angular, click, tooltip, hide, angular2-material

I am creating a sidebar. It should be composed by many icons, and when a user click on a specific Icon, redirect to a corresponding page.
but the problem is after clicking on a icon, tooltip (from angular2-material) does not hide, and after each click on a icon, its tooltip becomes fixed.

```
<md-sidenav-layout id="nav_container">
<md-sidenav #start opened="true" mode="side">
    <md-nav-list>
        <div id="nav_container">
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li>
                    <a routerLink="/groups" routerLinkActive="active">
                        <md-icon   >home</md-icon>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a routerLink="/contacts"  >
                        <md-icon md-tooltip="Contacts" onclick="iconClick" *ngIf="isFocues" >supervisor_account</md-icon>
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </md-nav-list>
</md-sidenav>
```

How can I hide tooltips after 10ms ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `MdTooltip` class implements [a `hide()` method](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/tooltip#methods) that you could use to programmatically hide your tooltip.

But your tooltip should not be stuck. It should go away when the mouse moves away.  Did you import the CSS styles into your `index.html`?

```
<link href="vendor/@angular2-material/core/overlay/overlay.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Hi,I imported overlay.css in the index.html file.But I think when I click on an icon, it gets focus. So tooltip is shown. On the other side, hide is a method, I think it is fired after disappearing tooltip. how can be hide after clicking on a item in menu?

Answer (score 0):

Am sure it fix your issue.

```
<md-tooltip md-autohide></md-tooltip>
```